# Is there a way to update a Progress View on one View Controller after pressing a button on a different View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working on an app that will generate tasks that a user can mark as "Complete" by pressing a button on the Root View Controller. I have a different View Controller that works as an "Achievements" page with a progress bar that I would like to be updated each time one of the three "Complete" buttons is pressed.

What I am struggling to figure out is a way to link the function of the button on the Root View Controller to the Progress View (outlet) on the other Achievements View Controller. I have attempted using a segue to pass that data, but it does not quite function how I would like it to. I do not want the user to be navigated to the Achievements page every time, I would just like the progress bar to update "in the background", and have that progress be seen when the Achievements page is opened.

I've searched for similar questions and answers, but nothing seems to be quite what I'm looking for. Am I missing a simple solution here to this problem?

Comment: you will try with delegate. or notification.

Comment: Try saving your value out to CoreData or UserDefaults if it's simple enough and load that value in the onViewDidLoad() of the Achievements page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to declare a global property that represents the progress, try checking some architectures.

UserDefaults is an easier and quicker way do the the trick, but I wouldn't use it for this, so you have to decide. In case of a smaller project don't worry use user defaults.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! Using UserDefaults, I was able to store a variable that was incremented by 1 each time a complete button was pressed and used that to update the progress view on the other page. Awesome!